# Getting message content of a embed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

:)
I'm trying to loop through the message history of a channel and if there's "Now playing" in the embed title it gets deleted. But I can't figure out how.

```
messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=200).flatten()
word = "Now playing"

for msg in messages:
    if word in msg.content:
        await msg.delete()
```

This is what I have now. But this doesn't work. It doesn't give any errors. Does looking for content in an embed work differently than in a normal message? And how can I make it work for an embed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`message.embeds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Message.embeds) to get the first embed of a message.

So your code would be:

```py
for msg in messages:
    if msg.embeds:
        if word in msg.embeds[0].title:
            await msg.delete()
```